# sh: /Users/mac/Desktop/LOGIC/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

How to fix it?
This error appears, when I run react project

sh: /Users/mac/Desktop/LOGIC/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an issue with Macintosh line endings. Open the file in an editor like Visual Studio Code and save the file with Unix (LF) line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the file react-scripts in the linux editor and save it. Now repeat the command.

Answer (score 0):

The ^M is a carriage return character. Linux uses the line feed character to mark the end of a line, whereas Windows uses the two-character sequence CR LF. Your file has Windows line endings, which is confusing Linux.
Remove the cariage character:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' NAME-OF-FILE.sh
```

From:
https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/07/bin-shm-bad-interpreter-with-code-examples.html